# What does the code do and what ODE is that?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

This exercise I came across asks what kind of method of solving ODE is that:

`function x1 = Solve(N,T)
   h = T/N;
   x1(1) = 0; x2(1) = 1;
   for k = 2:N
      x1(k) = 2*x1(k-1) + h*x2(k-1);
      x2(k) = x2(k-1) + h*x2(k-1)*x1(k-1)^2;
   end`

and the Matlab code also supposed to contain one error.

I guess, the error is in the following: `for k = 2:N` should be replaced with `for k = 2:N+1`.

But what does the code do? It must be a differential equation of the second order transformed to a system of first order.

\begin{align}
x^{(1)}_k & = 2x^{(1)}_{k-1} + h x^{(2)}_{k-1} \\
x^{(2)}_k & = x^{(2)}_{k-1} + h x^{(2)}_{k-1} (x^{(1)}_{k-1})^2 \\ 
\end{align}

The chapter I took it from doesn't discuss that many methods: forward Euler (and generally Taylor method), backward Euler, trapezoidal rule. But I can't recognize any of them in the code. Or maybe one needs to first see what kind of ODE the method is solving to see what the method is.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Might the error be the $2$ in the first term on the right-hand side of the equation for $x^{(1)}_{k}$? If that $2$ were a $1$ it looks like we'd have forward Euler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment: To me it looks like the update law
\begin{equation}
x_k^{(1)} = 2x^{(1)}_{k-1} + hx^{(2)}_{k-1}
\end{equation}
contains an error because of the $2$ coefficient in the first term on the right-hand side. If that were a $1$, we'd have a forward Euler update law for the ODE
\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = \left(\begin{array}{c} x_2 \\ x_2x_1^2 \end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
I've changed the superscript indices to subscripts, but hopefully the point is clear here.

Comment: I must admit that the exercise is quite badly formulated but it says "one error" and since we have $N$ intervals and an initial condition, we need to find $N$ values so $k$ must go from $2$ to $N+1$.

Comment: Hmm. Is it necessarily the case that that's an error? I take the arguments to the Solve function to mean we want a solution up to time $T$ with $N$ points, in which case $k$ from $2$ to $N$ seems fine.

Comment: And to what second order ODE would \begin{equation}
\dot{x} = \left(\begin{array}{c} x_2 \\ x_2x_1^2 \end{array}\right).
\end{equation} be equivalent?

Comment: To me the ODE being solved here is
\begin{equation}
\ddot{z} = \dot{z}z^2. 
\end{equation}

Comment: Very interesting. But then I still don't quite understand why did you say it is okay for $k$ to go from $2$ to $N$ for the `Solve` function to mean we want a solution up to time $T$ with $N$ points. I mean `h = T/N` implies we have $N$ intervals of length $h$, so we have $(N+1)$ points $t_0, \ldots, t_N$ with $t_0 = 0$ and $t_N = T$. The initial condition gives us the values at $t_0$ so we need to find an estimation for the values at  $t_1, \ldots, t_N$ (these are $N$ points) but if $k$ to go from $2$ to $N$ it's only $(N-1)$ points. I must be missing something.

Comment: I didn't really look at $h = T/N$, but you're right in saying that implies that we need $N+1$ points; $k$ probably *should* go from $2$ to $N+1$. My reason for ignoring that is that I was expecting a book on numerics to have the reader find an error in the discretization of the problem itself. It seems unlikely to me that they would make the error a loop index. My guess here is that the intent of the question is to have the error be in the update law and that  `k=2:N` is a typo. If the only typo is in that line, then I don't recognize the update law given here as any of the ones you mentioned.

Comment: Which leads me to believe that the book's intent is to have the reader notice the error in the update law (and I'm thinking that's the error they want you to find). My guess is that accidentally (as it's easy to do) a loop index was written incorrectly as well.